# display hidden div after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a user drop down menu in my form code where user can select their option to process their request. The `div` ids ranges from `fa1` to `fa8`.By default I am showing fa1 and fa2 in my form and `fa3` to `fa8` are set to `display: none`. I have added a button to add remove additional drop down menu depends upon user requirement( which will display\hide `fa3` to `fa8`)

I am able to keep the user selected options after form submit using

```
<option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
```

The issue I am facing here is if  user added a addiotnal div (say `fa3`), selected drop down option and submit the form, the hidden div not displaying after submit (eventhough it keeping its drop down as user selected)

I would like to show the hidden div(if user added) as well along with the selected option after form submit

My html code:

```
<div class="block-no-height">
            <div class="sub_headings"> Select Your FA director and Port</div>

            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa1">
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 1</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-1" name="fa-select-1">
                            <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-1']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option>                         
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-1" name="proc-select-1">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-1']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-1']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-1']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-1']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-1" name="port-select-1">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-1']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-1']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa2">
                    <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 2</div>
                    <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-2" name="fa-select-2">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-2']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-2" name="proc-select-2">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-2']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-2']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-2']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-2']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-2" name="port-select-2">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-2']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-2']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa3" style="display:none;" disabled="true">
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 3</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-3" name="fa-select-3">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-3']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-3" name="proc-select-3">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-3']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-3']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-3']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-3']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-3" name="port-select-3">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-3']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-3']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>


            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa4" style="display:none;" >
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 4</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-4" name="fa-select-4">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-4']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-4" name="proc-select-4">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-4']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-4']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-4']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-4']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-4" name="port-select-4">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-4']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-4']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa5" style="display:none;" >
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 5</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-5" name="fa-select-5">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-5']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-5" name="proc-select-5">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-5']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-5']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-5']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-5']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-5" name="port-select-5">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-5']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-5']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa6" style="display:none;" >
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 6</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-6" name="fa-select-6">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-6']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-6" name="proc-select-6">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-6']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-6']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-6']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-6']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-6" name="port-select-6">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-6']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-6']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa7" style="display:none;" >
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 7</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-7" name="fa-select-7">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-7']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-7" name="proc-select-7">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-7']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-7']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-7']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-7']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-7" name="port-select-7">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-7']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-7']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-quest-resp" id="fa8" style="display:none;" >
                <div class="input-quest-no-height">FA and port - 8</div>
                <div class="input-resp-no-height">
                        <select id="fa-select-8" name="fa-select-8">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Dir</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==1)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==2)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >2</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==3)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >3</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==4)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >4</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==5)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >5</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==6)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >6</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==7)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >7</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==8)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >8</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==9)  {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >9</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==10) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >10</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==11) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >11</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==12) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >12</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==13) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >13</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==14) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >14</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==15) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >15</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['fa-select-8']==16) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >16</option> 
                        </select>

                        <select id="proc-select-8" name="proc-select-8">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Proc</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-8']==a) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >a</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-8']==b) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >b</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-8']==c) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >c</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['proc-select-8']==d) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >d</option>
                        </select>

                        <select id="port-select-8" name="port-select-8">
                        <option disabled="disabled" SELECTED >Port</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-8']==0) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >0</option>
                            <option <?php if ($_POST['port-select-8']==1) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="add_remove_column">
                    <input  type="hidden" id="countfa" name="countfa" value="3" readonly>
                    <button type="button" onClick="AddNewFa();" id="addfa" > + Add New FA </button>
                    <button  type="button" onClick="RemoveNewFa();" id="removefa" disabled="disabled"> - Remove FA</button> 
            </div>

        </div>
```

My javascript to add\remove hidden divs(minimum it will show two divs and max 8, I have added to disable add or remove buttons depends upn on its max \min count)

```
function AddNewFa() 
    {
        var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),9) ;
        if( facount < 9)
            {
                facount = facount+1;

                for(i=3;i<9;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast"); 

                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount);  

            }
        if( facount ==9 )
            { $('#addfa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
        if( facount ==4 )
            { $('#removefa').removeAttr("disabled");}

    } 

//removing fa clicking remove button

function RemoveNewFa() 
    {
        var facount = parseInt($('#countfa').val(),10) ;
        if( facount >3)
            {
                facount = facount-1;

                for(i=3;i<10;i++)
                {
                    if( i<facount )
                        $('#fa'+i).slideDown("fast");
                    else
                        $('#fa'+i).slideUp("fast");                 
                }
                $('#countfa').val(facount); 
            }        
        if( facount ==3 )
            { $('#removefa').attr('disabled','disabled');} 
        if( facount =8 )
            { $('#addfa').removeAttr("disabled");       }   
    }
```

Comment: Are there errors in your JavaScript? In Firefox you can press control+shift+k and in Chrome you can press F12 to open the console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Maybe in your code you can `console.log` some values. Like `console.log("facount is now:",facount);` and `console.log("div to slide is:",$('#fa'+i)," i is:",i);`

Comment: Also, when you submit the form the whole page is reloaded so changes made to the DOM with JavaScript go away unless you re do them in your PHP code. Something like this: `style="<?php echo ($_POST['fa-select-8']==="")?"display:none;":""?>"`